# transfer files through sockets in c

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, file-transfer

I want to implement a program that transfer any files from the server to the client. I must use read/write functions to read and write data(its for school assignment). Here is the code for server and client.

**server.c**

```
    char buffer[512];        

    if( (file = open(strTable[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1 ) { perror("Open"); }

    while( read(file, buffer, sizeof(buffer)) != 0 )
    {
        size = strlen(buffer)+1;
        if( write(newsock, &size, sizeof(size)) < 0 ) { perror("Write"); exit(1); }

        write_all(newsock, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    }

    size = 4;
    if( write(newsock, &size, sizeof(size)) < 0 ) { perror("Write"); exit(1); }
    write_all(newsock, "end", 4);
```

It opens strTable[1] (which contains the file that i want to read) it reads sizeof(buffer) bytes and then i send to client how much bytes i will write to socket and after that i send the bytes. Here is write_all function.

```
int write_all(int sock, char* buffer, int size)
{
   int nwrite, sent = 0;

   while( sent < size )
   {
       if( (nwrite = write(sock, buffer + sent, size - sent)) < 0 ) 
       { perror("Write"); exit(1); }

       sent += nwrite;
   }

   return sent;
}
```

client.c

```
if( (file = open(absolute, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0644)) == -1 )
                { perror("Open"); }    

while( true )
        {
            received = 0;

            /* Read the desired readable size */
            if( read(sock, &size, sizeof(size)) < 0 ) 
            { perror("Read"); pthread_exit(NULL); }

            /* Read all data */
            while( received < size )
            {
                if( (nread = read(sock, buffer + received, size - received)) < 0 )
                { perror("Read"); pthread_exit(NULL); }

                received += nread;
            }

            if( strncmp(buffer, "end", 4) == 0 ) { break; }

            write_all(file, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
        }
```

The client opens a file (absolute) and writes in it what it reads. It first reads how much size it has to read and then it doesnt stop to read until it reaches that size. If the client reads "end" then server has stop the writing to the socket so the client stops reading.

The problem is that i cant open the files after the transfer. I read some images that i cant open. I read also and one file.txt which i write some random words, this seems to be copied right but it has some garbage too(its the photo number 2).  Why i getting this and how can i transfer files from sockets correctly?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ0Vg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdJQB.png)

Comment: The relevance of [tag:encoding] escapes me.

Comment: `read` and `write` both return a count of the number of bytes read or written, which may be less than requested.

Answer (score 1):

Usual problems. `read()` doesn't null-terminate the buffer, so using `strlen()` on it as the count isn't valid. A read/write loop should look like this:

```
int count;
while ((count = read(inFD, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    if (write(outFD, buffer, count) < 0)
    {
        perrror("write"); //  at least
        break;
    }
}
```

followed by error-handling as follows:

```
if (count < 0)
{
    perror("read"); // at least
}
```

Your second problem comes with assuming that `"end"` will be received by itself as a separate message. There is no guarantee of this. You will either have to use end of stream by closing the socket after each file, or else send the length ahead of each file and only read exactly that many bytes from the stream for each file. But as you are already sending the length, sending `"end"` is pointless anyway.

Comment: You also need to check the return value from `write` as it may write fewer than `count` bytes, in which case you'll need another write call to write more.

Comment: Particularly in non-blocking mode.  Some certain underlying objects (such as pipes and files) may guarentee that writes of less than a certain limit will never return short values, but you need to check that count is in fact less than that limit and outFD is something for which the limit applies...

Comment: @ChrisDodd Sorry, I mis-spoke. Not in *blocking* mode according to the Posix specification, but I should certainly have checked it for errors.

Comment: It works if i put count and not strlen(buffer). Thanks a lot! The server writes until it stops reads and every time he sends the data that client has to read. If the file is large and the server needs a lot of read calls to read it all then the client how would know when to stop? Thats why i put the "end". I think its a good way to an stat.buff to learn the size of the file first and make client read until he reads this size but is this not the same with end?

Comment: What happens if the file contains "end"? How do you know you will get the "end" as the only thing in the buffer?